# Github code browsing left navigation panel disappears

Tags: github, user-interface

I *know* this is *not* a programming issue per se, but I believe it is affecting every programmer as each of us need to do code browsing on github, yet sometimes github's left navigation panel will disappear, and I don't know what triggers it and how to avoid.

Take a look at this url for example,
https://github.com/goadesign/examples/tree/master/cellar

- If I click on any folders under the tree, the left navigation panel will still remains,
  [image]
- Yet, if I click on any files under the tree, whether in the left navigation panel or the right, the left navigation panel will be gone, and I have to pop it up manually.
  [image]
- Moreover, if I hit "back" from the browser, the left navigation panel will be missing *still*, whereas it was OK before.

This is really inconvenient and inconsistent, and I want the previous behavior back, to have the left navigation panel visible *all the time*. How to do that?